# Button doesn't show up tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a class that represents a Window that contains a canvas, a label and is soon to contain some color-coordinated buttons.

***Here is the code:***

```py
class Canvas():
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


        self.text_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="10",font=("Times New Roman", 20, "italic"))
        self.text_label.pack()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master= self.root,width = self.width,height = self.height)
        self.canvas.pack()

        

        #======================
        self.redBtn = tk.Button(master=self.root,text="hello",command=lambda:self.changeColor("Red"))
        self.redBtn.pack()
        #======================

        self.root.mainloop()
canvas = Canvas(1980,1080)
```

Although I used `redBtn.pack()` on the button it doesn't show up.
Does anyone know why?

[image: The window:]

Comment: When I run your code after adding enough code to make it run, the button appears along with the label and canvas.

Comment: @BryanOakley I dropped some of the code for ease of reading but when I run it It wont show up

Comment: The code you posted isn't enough for us to reproduce. Though, I only had to add two lines to run the code - an import statement, and then creating the instance of the class.

Comment: Can you help me out though? @BryanOakley

Comment: What resolution is your screen?  The Button might simply be pushed off the screen by the rather large size of the Canvas.

Comment: I can't help you out because I can't reproduce the problem. Your code works fine for me. By the way, your edit doesn't work. You define `Canvas` but create an instance of `Window`. My advice is to make sure you copy and paste your actual example into a separate file and then run it. When I fix that mistake  your code still works fine for me. Are you certain _this_ code behaves the way you describe?

Comment: you create `Canvas`/`Window` with size `1980,1080` - if your monitor has also size `1980,1080` then your  button is outside monitor and you can't see it . Use smaller `Canvas` - ie. `800,600` - and there will be place to show button.

Comment: Replace this win = Canvas(1980,1080)

Comment: Color for RED is bg or fg?

Comment: You need self.redBtn.grid. Even , change the size  win = Canvas(1980,900). So you can see button on bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked. I can see number 10. Change this:

```
win = Window(1980,1080)
```

to

win = Canvas(1980,900)

So you can see the button on bottom.